# Can I use the same SDK Android folder from Windows to Ubuntu?

Tags: java, android, visual-studio, sdk

I changed of OS from Windows to Ubuntu. I already downloaded so much files on SDK folder when i was utilizing Windows and now i want use it on Ubuntu, but it does not work.

Obs: I using Visual Studio and Java 8.

Comment: Welcome to SO! "it does not work" is not exactly a detailed error description, or is it? Please be more specific!

Comment: EmptyThrowable: Unable to locate adb within SDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I use the same SDK Android folder from Windows to Ubuntu?

No. Ubuntu cannot run Windows native code. The [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Requirements) is provided in different formats for various native platforms.

Comment: It that! What i want to know! Thanks :)